# Rails scope where has_one relation has no relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

Trip.rb

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :report
end
```

Report.rb

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Trips exist first, and then need a report. When a report gets created, it gets a trip_id. The relation works in that the console `Trip.report` shows the correct report

I'm trying to figure out how (presumably in the Trip model) to get a list of Trips that do not have a report through the relation

This seems like it should be straightforward, but I'm getting the sense it may not be.

`scope :need_report, -> { where(joins(:report)) }`

will get me the trips that have reports, but I'm trying to return the opposite.

Not sure if I should:

1. Return the opposite of the join
2. Nest and update the report_id to the trip somehow so it is easy to call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way (returns an array):

```
scope :no_report, -> { select { |trip| trip.report.blank? } }
```

It's also possible to get an `ActiveRecord::Relation`:

```
scope :no_report, -> { includes(:report).where(report: { id: nil })
```

Comment: That works, but provides as an array, which breaks the other methods on the scope, i.e. order, paginate, etc..

Comment: Sorry, long day. Appears I can run the order, paginate etc before calling the no_report scope

Comment: @RyanMcCrary fixed the answer

Comment: That's where I was trying to get, and just couldn't get there. Thanks so much!

Comment: @RyanMcCrary no problem!